# How to rotate label 90 degree below node in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-styles

i am trying for hours (:-) ) to annotate a node with a text of 90 degree with the "every label" method. While I can rotate the text, it's position is transferred to a greater distance somewhere in the picture. I would not to put the "rotate" directive to every node, I would rather define it with the "every label" style.

[image: Example every node]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,intersections,quotes,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\def \V {1.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={line width=0.1mm, minimum size=1cm}]
\tikzstyle{every label}=[rotate=-90]
    \node[label={[label distance=0.1cm]:A},  circle, draw] (A)  at (1,0) { A};    
    \node[draw, circle] (B)  at (2,0) {B};   
    \node[draw, circle]  (C)  at (3,0) {C};  
    \node[draw, circle]  (D) at (4,0) {D}; 
    \node[draw, circle]  (E) at (5,0) {E}; 
    \node[draw, circle]  (F) at (6,0)  {F}; 
    \node[draw, circle]  (G) at (1,\V) {G};
    \node[draw, circle]  (H) at (2,\V) {H};
    \node[draw, circle]  (I) at (3,\V) {I};
    \node[draw, circle]  (J) at (4,\V) {J};
    \node[draw, circle]  (K) at (5,\V) {K};
    \node[draw, circle]  (L) at (6,\V) {L};

    \draw[->]  (B) to [bend left=60] (K) ;

\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can position the label directly beneath the middle of the circle with: "   \node[label={[label distance=-0.5cm]below:label}, draw, circle] (A) at (1,0) {A}; "

Comment: But that is not what I want. I want to get more control over the position an place it outside the circle

Answer (score 2):

You only need to define anchor of label after rotating command:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,intersections,quotes,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\def \V {2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
          C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1cm},% every node influence on label node too,
every label/.style = {label distance=0pt, inner sep=1pt}
                    ]
    \node[C,label={[rotate=90, anchor=east]below:A}] (A)  at (1,0) { A};
    \node[C]  (B) at (2,0) {B};
    \node[C]  (C) at (3,0) {C};
    \node[C]  (D) at (4,0) {D};
    \node[C]  (E) at (5,0) {E};
    \node[C]  (F) at (6,0)  {F};
    \node[C]  (G) at (1,\V) {G};
    \node[C]  (H) at (2,\V) {H};
    \node[C]  (I) at (3,\V) {I};
    \node[C]  (J) at (4,\V) {J};
    \node[C]  (K) at (5,\V) {K};
    \node[C]  (L) at (6,\V) {L};

    \draw[->] (B.north) .. controls + (0,1) and + (0,-1) .. (K.south) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I found the solution: to position the label into the place I want to, I have to add an "xshift":

```
\node[label={[label distance=-0.5cm,red, xshift=-.5cm]below:label}, draw, circle] (A)  at (1,0) {A};
```

[image: Positioning of the node label]